# 301 redirect vs. wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I am getting really desperate over here. 
In order to make up some SEO I want to redirect my none-www into www site. Of course simple 301 redirect ill d the trick, and it also work.

BUT

What doesn't work, at all, is a wordpress. I have my own VPS, and I am installing wordpress by application manager in plesk panel. But if i activate the htaccess file, wordpress cannot be installed anymore (strangely enough it tells me that mysql extension is not activated) and existing wordpress pages will stop orking with infinite loop error. Once I delete htaccess everything works fine.

Please if anyine has idea how can i redirect and have wordpress at the same, it would me much appreciated

Comment: What is in your .htaccess files?

Comment: This is the htaccess: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webakery.asia
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.webakery.asia/$1 [R=301,L] `

Answer (score 0):

Bypass the problem. Set up a simple `example.com` domain/site in Apache, and force it to unconditionally redirct to `www.example.com`. Wordpress would only be active in the `www.example.com` site's setup, and example.com exists ONLY to redirect to the www version.

That way you're not trying to get your .htaccess stuff to coexist with Wordpress', and the redirection occurs far outside of Wordpress' domain.

Comment: im not sure if we are at the same page. I am trying to redirect webakery.asia into www.webakery.asia . the wordpress is at www.webakery.asia/blog. Can you describe more what you suggesting please?